# Webforms asp:Panel children not showing fully in VS 2012

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2012, webforms

I'm wrestling with design time rendering of my custom WebForms components where I have defined a control derived from Panel and a second control derived from WebControl.

I place the WebControl inside the Panel by dragging and dropping from the Toolbox. The problem I have is that at design time when I drag and drop the component within the Panel, the Paint method of the WebControl's designer is being executed immediately but the image generated by the interpretation of the getDesignTimeHtml and the application of the CSS rules is being executed a varying number of seconds later, typically between 1 and 4 seconds.

So my component is being drawn twice by two different pieces of logic. How can I synchronize these events so they both are executed at the same time? Having to wait for a ghost image to clean itself up is distracting for the developer. Note if I place the WebControl outside the Panel both methods are called at the same time, and they are called immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One solution is to invoke the `Invalidate()` method of the `PanelContainerDesigner` that belongs to the parent `System.Web.UI.WebControls.Panel`. Invoke this from the `OnPaint()` method of the child component's `Designer`.

To prevent needless looping, let the child component's `Designer` remember and verify its position data on each `OnPaint()` call, and only invoke `Invalidate()` on the `PanelContainerDesigner` if there is a real change.